# JXCollapsiblePane toggle not handled correctly

Tags: java, swing, java-7, swingx, jtogglebutton

i try to use JXCollapsiblePane (SwingX version 1.6.5.1) in a Java 7 Swing application. When writing a small test app i see the following problems:

- the toggle button is not in sync with the collapsible pane, i.e. i first have to click the button and only then it's in sync with the pane's state
- i only see one icon (collapsed or expanded) which always stays the same, regardless in which toggle state we are

I use the following code which is SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXCollapsiblePane;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXFrame;

public class JXCollapsiblePaneBsp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JXFrame frame = new JXFrame("JXCollapsiblePane-Example", true);

        JPanel container = new JPanel();
        container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(new TestContainer());

        JXCollapsiblePane cp = new JXCollapsiblePane();
        cp.setAnimated(true);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Text");
        label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        JButton butt = new JButton("click");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        panel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(butt);
        cp.add(panel);

        JPanel northContainer = new JPanel();
        northContainer.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JLabel title = new JLabel("Test");
        northContainer.add(title, BorderLayout.WEST);

        Action toggleAction =  cp.getActionMap().get(JXCollapsiblePane.TOGGLE_ACTION);
        toggleAction.putValue(JXCollapsiblePane.COLLAPSE_ICON, UIManager.getIcon("Tree.expandedIcon"));
        toggleAction.putValue(JXCollapsiblePane.EXPAND_ICON, UIManager.getIcon("Tree.collapsedIcon"));
        JToggleButton toggleButt = new JToggleButton(toggleAction);
        toggleButt.setText(""); 
        northContainer.add(toggleButt, BorderLayout.EAST);

        container.add(cp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        container.add(northContainer, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setStartPosition(JXFrame.StartPosition.CenterInScreen);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    } 
}
```

Is this a compatibility problem or what am i doing wrong here ?
Thank you!

UPDATE: After debugging the code for some hours now i can say that the problem seems to be not finishing animations. The timer always cancels events and therefore a started animation (up or down) can never come to an end.
When setting

```
cp.setAnimated(false);
```

the expand/collapse actions work fine (of course without animation).